# When will we be ready to launch the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Technically speaking, we can launch the blog just about any time; the Wordpress site is all set up (without content) and it can go live basically any time. What I want to know is **when do we think we'll be ready to launch the blog?**

We're having a rocky start and that's alright; it's a big undergoing and things won't go smooth until we've proven we can do it. I'm sure there's some hesitation to contribute to a thing that's not really *there* yet and I know plenty of you have become busy since we planned to start a blog.

We have content we could put out there at reasonable notice, but before we launch I want to **hammer out a realistic schedule** so we can *keep up momentum* once we launch.
**How much content do we need to launch and at what schedule?**

Comment: Step 1) Launch Step 2) write another post Step 3) write another post Step 4) write another post

Comment: @Rahul I just don't want to launch without something we can back up

Comment: Mmmh Id like to see this question slightly modified and posted as a real question on the *main*.

Comment: @Knu modified how? It's really meta content, not main. I have featured it so it shows up in the community bulletin but that's about all I can do to show it on the main site

Comment: @ben this could be a great UX question about users' expectations, posting frequency, content variation etc.   I would certainly be interested about studies or personal observations.

Comment: @Knu I still have no idea how that would directly relate to our situation, or how it would be generalizable...some blogs update once a day, some once a year, Popularity and success appear largely uncorrelated with release windows. I'm asking what *we* can do, not what generally tends to work, that's what matters.

Comment: @BenBrocka it seems you are assuming a lot of things; for example the timing (which days, after/before an event, night/day etc) impacts the user's awareness and how he consumes the content. There are probably studies done for news website but blog post *consumption* is clearly more laid-back…

Answer (score 1):

Counting items ready for review we've got 4 articles more or less ready to go, and 9 in various states of Work in Progress.  I *am* hoping we'll pick up the pace once we're in the groove, but I'm thinking we should start slower.

Currently I'm thinking a schedule of one or two posts a month (perhaps straying to one post to start) would be best so we have plenty of time to figure out the details as we go and make sure we put out the best possible content.

Comments or alternate answers/schedules are welcome.