# Do we close off topic "Community Wiki" questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I'm doing some cleaning in the archives this weekend and I found the question [What are some great web-based prototyping tools?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/375/4679) which is a community wiki question. However [tool request questions have been declared as off topic](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1180/4679) by the community.

So what do I do with this off topic community wiki question? Flag to close or leave as is since it's a community wiki?

Comment: Not so much Off Topic as Not Constructive. "How to do X in specific tool Y" is off topic for a different reason. I guess in practice there's not much difference. But to me, community wiki status doesn't matter; if it's close worthy it is, if it isn't, it isn't.

Comment: @BenBrocka I might have guessed, but Wikis sounds like a middle state in between valid question and closed question.

Comment: There's a reason wiki stopped being easy to apply to answers; that's no longer a valid use for Community Wiki (though some sites like Mathematics still do that I guess)

Comment: @BenBrocka Is this new? I got one of my questions on SharePoint.SE to be community wiki in july 2012. If it's not new I guess SharePoint uses it also.

Comment: The button for CW on questions has been removed for months, I think since I've been on SE, in fact

Comment: **Just to note,** the 'community wiki' status should have absolutely ***no*** (as in *zero*) bearing on whether the question is deemed as 'off topic' or 'not constructive' or whatever — See [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the site rules, it should be closed. It is tantamount to a "shopping request" - types of questions that are pretty much closed as soon as they are found by moderators.