# Update FAQ to state that tool recommendation questions are out of scope

Tags: discussion, feature-request, faq-contents

Over the past four months there has been a lot of discussion about the Tool category.  The general consensus seems to be that in most cases, these questions are out of scope.  That is the direction the majority is going, so it is time that we codify this in the FAQ.

The current system of playing whack-a-mole when these questions come up is not working.

It is not working because it is reactionary, and creates moments of exasperation which result in [shouty](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tags:

> PLEASE THINK CAREFULLY IF YOU WANT TO USE THIS TAG! REQUESTS FOR TOOL RECOMMENDATIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC FOR STACK EXCHANGE SITES. Hardware or Software tools used by UX professionals to do their work. Also more generally software used by users to shape or modify something they are creating.

It is not working because it creates a horrible experience for our new users, which does not create a welcoming atmosphere and will potentially drive away new users that might otherwise have made valuable contributions to the community.

Previously in [another meta question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/should-tool-related-questions-be-on-topic) I wrote the following regarding the current FAQ:

> I don't think it would be the end of the world to keep the "policy" as-is, however I think it should be more clearly articulated in the FAQs just to avoid having this discussion over and over.
>
> Currently when one of these questions is closed, the following message appears:
>
> > Questions on User Experience - Stack Exchange are expected to relate to user experience within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [closed questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#close) here.
>
> When you consult the [FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq), there is no mention of tools being out of scope.  In fact, the language is written in such a way that it encourages "practical" questions related to "actual problems":
>
> > You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
> >
> > Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
> >
> > If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> By that measure, a [specific question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29836/axure-checkbox-interactions-3-cases-none-checked-1-checked-or-2-checked) about how to use a UX tool is entirely valid *according to the **stated** policy*.
>
> In my case I wondered if it would be in scope or out of scope, and was leaning towards not asking the question *until I read the FAQ*.  As it is written, it encouraged me to post my question.  Which was downvoted and closed.

**I would like to formally propose we update the FAQ to be more explicit that Tools questions are out of scope.  Additionally, we could include some language in the close message to reinforce this as well.**

**Update**: I edited the tag wiki for [tools](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) to include a blurb about what is out of scope for the topic.  I also included a few links to alternate resources.

Perhaps when an off topic question is posted a link to this wiki could be provided.

A link to the wiki may also be helpful in the FAQ.

I believe it will help those who do prior research before posting to not ask an off topic question, and it will give us a "canned" response to give to people who do ask an off topic question.

The "canned" response will hopefully help them get the answer they need, and will improve their experience on this site.

Even though we are downvoting/closing their question (which is a negative experience), we are softening the blow by giving them somewhere else to go.

It's the difference between "Go away" and slamming the door in someone's face versus saying "I'm sorry I can't help you by try down the street, thanks!".

Answer (score 1):

The closure reasons are currently in the process of being updated, but the FAQ will also be considered for updation and amendment.

To quote [Stack Exchange developer Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv?noredirect=1#comment509580_171732)

> we agree. We are already working on an FAQ overhaul, which we'll share for input once we've got a little more done. The key question here is what we can do to address the problem best for someone who doesn't get to the FAQ. But you're dead right - we can use it to augment and improve it even further for those who do. More to come on that soon.

Comment: Very timely, thanks for sharing.  I appreciate your consideration!

Comment: @JonW, as a site moderator, you can update the FAQ for this site - the ["What can I ask here?" section](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) is editable on every site. You can insert a section that explicitly states things that are off-topic here, like tool recommendations. You don't need to wait for us (SE, Inc.) to do that. (You can [see](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) some [examples](http://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) of how [other](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) sites wrote theirs.)

Comment: @Laura Yes, we've already done so on our site too, although covering off things you *Can't* ask within the *what can i ask* section seems... contradictory.

Comment: You're correct. As Jaydles mentioned over on MSO, we're working on a big overhaul of the FAQ, and I hope to iron out things like that contradiction. In the meantime, you can style it to make the "off-topic" section *look* like it's own section of the FAQ; it just won't have an anchor link on it, which shouldn't matter too much since it's at the top of the page

Comment: Updation is not a word. please change the first sentence to the following "The closure reasons are currently in the process of being updated, but the FAQ will also be considered for update and amendment." see this [Is 'Updation' a correct word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68169/is-updation-a-correct-word)