# Topic of the Week Contest (UPDATED Feb. 4th)

Tags: discussion

This is a quick way to both expand and enrich the scope of the site, as well as generate new questions.

This is also related to the [Stack Improvement Drive](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/stack-improvement-drive-ux-updated-12-4). Right now, the sites Qs/day is a down to around 7-8, but I think we can work on upping that number. **The goal is to get the Qs/day up to 15** by the end of January 2013.

**How it works:** One topic will be designated each week. Each person who [asks a question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize. The current topic is listed below.

**How to enter:** [Ask a question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly. Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win one of the following prizes:

- If your country is regularly serviced by an online Amazon store without exorbitant shipping costs, you can choose an item of your choice (under $50 USD)
- If your country is not serviced by an online Amazon store, you will receive a UX.SE and Stack Exchange swag package of exclusive merchandise.

The difference in prizes is due to the difference in cost for us to ship to various parts of the world.

The question must have a score of 0 or greater and not be closed or deleted to be eligible. **Users may only win once in a four week period.**

**Choosing the topic of the week:** If you have suggestions for a future topic, **please leave them as answers to this post.** Topics must be trackable with a tag, and that tag should have a tag wiki filled out.

---

**Current Topic: [navigation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation)**

Any questions correctly tagged [navigation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) will be eligible for the prize. Questions posted before **Monday, February 11, 2012 at 5 AM UTC** will be eligible. Winners will be picked and notified on Mondays at approximately **2 PM UTC**.

---

**WINNERS:**

- Dec. 12th: [janoChen](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/3596/janochen) - [user behavior question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30190/are-users-less-likely-to-engage-in-a-site-where-the-content-they-are-posting-tak)
- Dec. 19th: [redhotspike](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/17524/redhotspike) - [mobile question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30743/coloring-schemes)
- Dec. 26th: [Benny Skogberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4679/benny-skogberg) - [information architecture question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/should-we-use-narrow-and-deep-or-broad-and-shallow-navigation-pattern-on-mob)
- Jan. 2nd: [Benny Skogberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4679/benny-skogberg) - [accessibility question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/are-support-for-voice-browsers-really-necessary)
- Jan. 9th: [Tims](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/22708/tims) - [hci question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31395/should-we-be-designing-for-touch-first)
- Jan. 21st: [Riyaz Mohammed Ibrahim](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/24966/riyaz-mohammed-ibrahim) - [physical question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33219/why-google-opted-out-of-hardware-buttons-from-nexus-devices)
- Jan. 28th: [Uri](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/25267/uri) - [gui-design question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/scrollbar-width-in-component-vs-containers-ux-dilemma)
- Feb. 4th: [Mark D](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/15413/mark-d) - [web app question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/adding-a-state-to-a-control-that-indicates-a-row-hasnt-been-saved-yet)

Comment: This is a better place to give rewards because you're rewarding the behaviour (asking a question) rather than rewarding the badge (getting the announcer badge).

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to suggest the topic: mobile

Comment: This week is tag:mobile week!

Comment: woohoo! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Can I suggest a topic of [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) as one of / the next tags?

Comment: Accessibility week is go!

Answer (score 3):

Lovely!

I think this is a great idea! And it could be even better if we (the system) could color the tag currently in the contest. Like the feature tag in red here on Meta. Is that possible? As of today - the tag info isn't really that [visible](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/user-behavior/info) while tagging.

Next tag to pick I’d suggest would be [information-architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-architecture) or [hci](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hci).

Comment: Agree with Information-architecture suggestion. We really need more of those questions on this site.

Comment: Information Architecture week is go!

Comment: Thank you @BrettWhite :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend [hci](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hci) in the hopes of more questions that are academic or formal in nature.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to focus heavily on UX as it relates to computer interaction.  I'd like to see something more on physical products.  I suggest the tag [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical)

Comment: You're probably right, and it would help expand the site to have more of these. But personally speaking I do shudder when I see a question tagged 'physical' because we don't half get some daft questions around this.

Comment: @JonW I love the physical question, and would like to read an answer from Donald Norman discussing [Why do most public toilet doors open inwards?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/why-do-most-public-toilet-doors-open-inwards)!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to make the tag for that week a sticky or something so that more people know about it? I rarely visit meta stack exchange and I suspect a lot of users dont as well and this way we might me missing out on some great questions

Comment: Right now, the only thing we can do to advertise the TotW contest is put it in the Community Bulletin.

Answer (score 0):

Do we need to make a rules adjustment for multiple-time winners now?

Comment: Updated restricting winners to once every four weeks!