# Announcer Badge Reward

Tags: discussion

In an effort to increase the number of visitors per day to the site and up the site's visibility, we will be rewarding users who receive the **[Announcer Badge](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer)** from the time of this post's publishing until the time when our visitors/day goal has been met.

The visitors/day goal for UX to reach is **three consecutive days with a minimum of 7250** visitors.

The **[Announcer Badge](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer)** is won by sharing a link to a question that is visited by 25 unique IP addresses. While this badge can be awarded multiple times, a user can only receive the award once (the nature of the prize may make multiple rewards redundant). The share tools can be found by clicking on "share" on a question's page, like so:

[image]

Winners will be rewarded with a Stack Exchange prize package.

For more information on this and other opportunities to improve UX.SE, please see the [Stack Improvement Drive](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/stack-improvement-drive-ux-updated-12-4).

---

The following users have been rewarded:

- **[edgarator](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/13689/edgarator)**

Comment: So what was the reward? :)

Comment: @edgarator It's a Stack Exchange prize package, including UX.SE merchandise. I sent an email to the one listed in your profile on December 11th but never heard back. Please contact me at brett at stack exchange dot com with your address, and we will get it shipped to you!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this kind of mess with the intrinsic nature of badges? I was under the impression that the Stack Exchange game is one where you do it for the reputation you stand to gain from it and for "the love of the sport", not from the real world money rewards you're eligible to win.

In other words, this may cause a short term boost due to people coming in and doing this in order to win something (and subsequent people being attracted to the site due to more links being shared), but how does this really improve use of UX.SE in the long term?

Comment: The hope is that by giving our established users incentive to promote and share content on this site, we will attract more people that are interested in this subject matter and will therefore contribute to the site. In the long term, this initiative will improve UX.SE by bringing in new, engaged users who can contribute quality questions and answers. If this proves to do more damage than good, then we will forget about it and try other things.

Comment: Good call! Always worth trying something new. Thanks for the explanation.